# Is there a hook or event we can use to intercept a search request?

Tags: plugin-development, search

We are looking to log searches so we can report on them. Are there any hooks or events we can use to get this data?

If not, then how can a custom plugin log the initial search parameters, call the underlying core Craft search, and finally log the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We are looking to log searches so we can report on them. Are there any
>   hooks or events we can use to get this data?

No, there aren't any hooks or events related to searching, currently (Craft 2.4). Like Brad says, you can [add a feature request](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/).

> [...] how can a custom plugin log the initial search parameters, call the
>   underlying core Craft search, and finally log the results?

Something like this should work:

```
class MyPluginVariable
{

    public function search($query = '', ElementType $elementType = null)
    {

        MyPluginPlugin::log($query);

        $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria($elementType ?: ElementType::Entry);
        $criteria->search = $query;

        MyPluginPlugin::log(count($criteria));

        return $criteria;

    }

}
```

...and in the template:

```
{% set entries = craft.myPlugin.search('body:foo -body:bar') %}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you'd need would be an `onBeforeSearch` or `onSearch` event.

There currently isn't anything like that in Craft, but would probably be worth adding as a [feature request](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com)!

Comment: Assuming I write a plugin then, how could i intercept the entries method, or can't I?

Comment: Wait... what are you trying to log?  I assumed anything that went through the SearchService.

Comment: Yes that's right, but I was hoping we could latch onto craft.entries.search('body:foo -body:bar'), but I guess not? If that's the case and we instead have a plugin that in twig looks like craft.myplugin.search('body:foo -body:bar'), how can we (in the plugin) defer the processing onto the core search functionality once we've done our logging?

Comment: Just pass it off to the SearchService like normal?

Comment: FYI: I just added the [feature request](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/8267127-add-events-for-onbeforesearch-and-onsearch) :)